# Generate random sequence of letters of length K from list of letters

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that generates a random sequence of letters (letters from a list), and the sequence length is K (K is passed to the function as an argument when function is called). I am stuck, and I don't understand how to generate random sequence of letters.

Comment: For one random letter of a sequence (e.g. a list) there is `random.choice`. Then just repeat it.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by we can loop the random choice on the given list for k times to get the desired output

```
Def fn(letters,k):

     return [np.random.choice(letters) for _ range(k) ]]
```

Comment: Why negative score file for this answer

Comment: Added the explanation